# Where do you set/change the SKU for a new/existing product? - Drupal 7 Commerce

Tags: commerce

i can't seem to find where to change the sku for an existing product variation. is this even possible? Where do i set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the product SKU on the product edit form.

e.g:

**admin/commerce/products/1/edit**

Because products are referenced on line-items etc.. by their ID value, it's actually OK to change SKU for existing products if needed.

Comment: no where on that page has an input field to change the SKU: http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/5450/croppercapture228.jpg

Comment: David Thomas has the correct answer, but you appear to be using some additional module that is hiding the SKU field. Could it be something like Commerce Auto SKU? It could be some custom code on your site, too... not much anyone else will be able to do to help you there.

Comment: Hi Ryan, seems like it is Commerce Auto SKU that is causing the issue. It's a fresh kickstarter 2.0 install too. Would be great if we can override this auto-sku feature by showing the input box if we need it.

Comment: @duckx there's a issue queue request for that "manual SKU override" with commerce_autosku here: http://drupal.org/node/1569450